# ngFor doesn't print object data

Tags: angular

I receive an object from socket, which I want to print to the screen using *ngFor. I get below error in console
[Error trying to diff 'asd'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhnQy.png)

angular ts

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log('ngOnInit');
this.socket.on('online',(people:number)=>{
  console.log('online:',people);
})
this.socket.on('message',(data:any)=>{
  console.log('socket-emit:',data);
})
this.socket.on('msg',(data:any)=>{
  console.log(data);
  this.MessageList = data; 
  for(let key in data){
    this.MessageList.push(key);
  }
  // console.log(this.MessageList['name'] ,":",this.MessageList['message']);
})


}
```

angular html

```
  <div *ngIf="MessageList">
          <li *ngFor="let m of MessageList">
            <span>{{m}}</span>

          </li>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you see the data in your console when you do console.log(data)?

Comment: It looks like you are receiving an object, instead you should get an array of object. For example, you should get [{message:"something", name : "abc"}, {message: "anotherthing", name: "pqr"}]

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your MessageList to empty array first

```
this.MessageList = [];
```

then as the error says ngFor supports only iterables such as arrays. so once you push the key it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

When `msg` socket is called, it passes only a single message object instead of whole array.

As such, you should not initialize your `this.MessageList = data` as it will convert your `MessageList` array to object, thereby making it non-iterable.

To get whole message list, you either have to:

- create new socket event, or
- update the existing event param data.

Below is a snippet reflecting that;

```
this.socket.on('msg', (data:any) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.MessageList = data; 
    for(let key in data) {
        this.MessageList.push(key);
    }
    // console.log(this.MessageList['name'], ":" , this.MessageList['message']);
});
```